# How to enqueue a style using wp_enqueue_scripts()?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I'm having difficult to load the path correctly in an 'enqueue' function.

What I am trying to achieve is to load a specific CSS stylesheet on a specific page...

The below works by adding the path to the markup on the correct template - but - the path is wrong...

```
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','homepage');
  function homepage(){
    if ( is_page_template('page-home.php') ) {
      wp_enqueue_style('home-css', array(), '1.0.0', true );
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flags.min.css',
    }
  }
```

The reason is because (I believe) the path is not set correctly to find the appropriate css folder...

The php is therefore missing this line:

```
get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flags.min.css',
```

My question is - how do I add this line that locates the theme css folder? I tried the below **but it did NOT work...**

```
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','homepage');
  function homepage(){
   if ( is_page_template('page-home.php') ) {
      wp_enqueue_style('home-css', array(), '1.0.0', true );
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flags.min.css',
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) is an optional path.You are passing an empty array, which will enqueue nothing.

[`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) retrieves the current theme's root URI, which you can use in `wp_enqueue_style()`:

```
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','homepage');
  function homepage(){
   if ( is_page_template('page-home.php') ) {
      wp_enqueue_style('home-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flags.min.css', '1.0.0', true );
    }
   }
```

I mentioned *"Optional"*, since there is also another way to use `wp_enqueue_style`. In this method, you can first use `wp_register_style`, and then enqueue it:

```
wp_register_style( 'home-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flags.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style('home-css');
```

The same works for `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Based on using parent theme or child, you might also want to take a look into [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) too.

Comment: OK cool - thanks for that - also - I've made an error with calling wp_enqueue_scripts? The file I am trying to call is .css so I guess it should be wp_enqueue_styles?

Comment: There is no such function as `wp_enqueue_styles()`. The name _"wp_enqueue_scripts"_ might be misleading, since it enqueues both styles and scripts.

Comment: My pleasure Henry :)